edge to edge in jetpack compose does not implied to navigation bar
i want to make my app edge to edge . i call enableEdgeToEdge() and my screen extends over statusBar  but not navigationBar . my screen layout doesn't go under the navigation bar . shouldn't edge to edge implied to both?

Based on the Android dev documentation here,

By default, enableEdgeToEdge() makes the system bars transparent,
except on 3-button navigation mode where the status bar gets a
translucent scrim. The colors of the system icons and the scrim are
adjusted based on the system light or dark theme.

So if you're under API 28, you probably have the 3 button navigation instead of the gesture navigation.
You can hide the navigation bar by adding
 val windowInsetsController =
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
        // Optional, Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars.
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE

        windowInsetsController.hide(
            WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars()
        )

Hope this helps
